# asp chart refreshing unnecessarily in web forms c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, webforms

I have an `asp chart` that refreshes whenever I click a button even when the whole form is inside `Update panel`. Other controls like text boxes are not refreshing (which is okay) but only the chart that refreshes.

```
         <asp:Button runat="server" id="btnPostback" style="display:none" onclick="Chart1_Click" />
         <div class="recent-report__chart" onclick="document.getElementById('<%= btnPostback.ClientID %>').click()">
            <asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" Width="600px" Palette="EarthTones">
                <Series>
                    <asp:Series Name="Series1" />
                </Series>
                <ChartAreas>
                    <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1"></asp:ChartArea>
                </ChartAreas>
            </asp:Chart>
        </div>
```

As it is clear in the code that I am calling the button `btnPostback's` click event by clicking on the chart. The moment I click the button it performs it functionality but the chart clears its data.

Comment: Have u used Page.IsPostBack

Comment: yes i have used it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case any one stumbles upon this question, I solved this by setting `EnableViewState` of the asp chart to `true`.